# Verify object in nodejs assert Or Chai

Tags: node.js, assert, chai

I'm trying achieve a very simple task of validating a returned object, 
Object is :

```
{ bids: 
   [ { i: 19546,
       f: 1,
       p: 5,
       s: 0,
       n: 'SPOTX',
       g: 172,
       b: 0,
       st: 1499711400000,
       et: 0,
       sdv: 0,
       sip: 0,
       dfp: 0,
       def: 1 } ] }
```

I just want to validate that returned value is a object and it has bids array.

I tried nodejs assert.equal, deepEuqal and chai's chai.expect(value).to.equal('{bids:[]}'); but nothing worked.

anyone has any idea ?

Comment: I think this solved my problem :
chai.expect(json).to.be.an('object').to.nested.property('bids');

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the values, you can try :

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
expect(function(args).to.deep.equal( {} );
```

http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/